# Burninate / clean up the [do] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

The [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do) tag (x228) is in need of a bit of a clean-up / burnination.

[There are a few occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do+while-loop) of it being used to indicate the [do-while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do-while) loop, which has its own tag.

[There's a do element in WML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do+wml) (x1) - possibly use [wml-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wml-do).

[There's a do loop in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do+sas) (x10) - presumably use [do-loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do-loops) (which also needs a bit of a clean-up - this tag is often used to refer to [do-while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do-while) loops).

[There are questions that seem to have this tag for no reason whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771069/calculate-industry-concentration-in-stata-based-on-four-biggest-numbers).

I think the tag usage so far showed that it's better to just get rid of it.

I may tend to this myself if I get some time, although feel free to comment on any aspect of this, especially about do in WML (if one question is worth its own tag, assuming there aren't others, if the do element is a standard thing, or if that's just applicable to that one person's project) and [do-loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do-loops).

Comment: Perhaps the one that used it "for no reason" thought it just meant, "Do this thing!  Now!" =P

Comment: Do the needings.

Comment: I think `do-while` should be a synonym for `while-loop`, since I can't see a situation in which people want to search for `while-loop` questions but don't want the `do-while` questions...

Comment: There's also the completely unrelated `do` notation in Haskell for representing monadic computations.

Comment: See the subsequent discussion about the tag in November 2022: [Let's \[do\] some blacklisting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421574/1478931)

Answer (score 7):

As has been pointed out elsewhere tags are for helping people find questions possibly to help answer because they are an expert in the subject.  Can someone be a `do` expert?  I think it should go.  It adds no clarity only confusion.

Answer (score 6):

I've removed the [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do) tag from all questions that had both the [do-while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do-while) and [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do) tag. That means there are 69 questions left with [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do) + [while-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/while-loop), which should have a more precise cleanup to see if it is really relevant to have the [do-while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do-while) for those questions.