# What do I need to regard when cleaning up a tag?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

The [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) tag is marked as being burninated*:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!! This tag is too general to be useful

And I have seen some users clean up the questions, by removing the Microsoft tag (and eventually adding others or editing the question).

Although I do not consider myself an expert on this topic, I think that this is a task on which I could be of some help. But I want to make sure, that I really am, and that my edits are somewhat well percieved.

I read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) and [some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283163/removing-phrases-like-i-looked-everywhere-on-the-internet-and-i-did-not-find-an) [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250950/burninate-clean-up-the-do-tag) [posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284167/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags), but as most of the remaining posts are more than a year old, I want to know if there are more things I need to bear in mind, or whether I should not do any edits alltogether and leave it to more experienced users.
For example, should I flag posts I that I think are too broad or off-topic, even though they might have been answered years ago?

**Edit:**

I consider this question related, but not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work) post.
Reading it was quite useful, but it's content does primarily adress, what burnination is, and when or why it should be done.
The following points were especially interesting to me:

> However, burnination should not be done by everyone. You should have:
>
> - Good judgement
> - Decent English skills (to fix other issues, including
>     spelling and grammar)
> - Patience or a love of burnination
> - Extensive knowledge of what's appropriate for the site (to know what should be closed, whether, on an individual question, a tag should simply be removed or perhaps replaced with something else, and what other issues you should fix in the post)
>
> [...]
>
> Additionally, if you have below 2000 reputation, it's especially important to fix all other issues with a post, as there's some work involved in actually getting your edit approved, and it may get rejected if it doesn't fix all issues
>
> [...]
>
> Preferably only remove the tags from questions you're sure are okay, and flag or vote to close those you're sure aren't okay, and leave the rest for someone else.

These points were very helpful, but I am still interested in things that need to be reminded when editing. E.g.

- If a post only contains minor spelling mistakes, should I remove them, as the post is understandable as is, and as I am still below 2k rep, a peer review on such edit would provide more work than use?
- Should I flag questions that I think are too broad or off-topic even though they are long answered? For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268915/where-to-find-more-info-on-visual-studio-2010-package-development) question is off-topic as it requires for off-site ressources and the like. It has however three upvoting and multiple answers. Should it be removed?

---

**heard this word the first time today - I love it :D*

Comment: Start by earning the right to edit posts...

Comment: I did long time ago. Having my edits reviewed is one of the influencing aspects of my question.