# Let's [do] some blacklisting

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, blocklist-request

The tag [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do) has [been burninated in 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250950/burninate-clean-up-the-do-tag).

However, it was [recreated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do) (even though there are not many questions).

I can imagine this tag being created and removed frequently.

Therefore, I propose to remove and blacklist the [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do)-tag to never be recreated again.

For the error message, I propose:

> Please use a more specific tag to describe the subject of your question.
> For example, use [do-while] for questions regarding do-while loops or [do-loops] for questions about do-loops which are not do-while loops.

Comment: And how do you propose to check if there won't be a technology that names itself to [tag:do] like the the tag [tag:go] ? This kind of blacklisting needs maintenance, who is going to do this ?

Comment: @Thingamabobs then we give them a disambiguated tag, i.e. [do-lang] if it's a language

Comment: [do] is very ambigous. It could refer to loops (do-while and there also seem to be other do-loops in languages like Fortran and lisp (?)) but it could also refer to any action (I want to [do] xyz).

Comment: [status-bug] How could this tag even resurface to begin with? The 3 posts with the tag presently were created by users with 1 rep, 313 rep and 17 rep respectively. They should not have the ability to create new tags, you should have 1500 rep for that (which is still far too low).

Comment: @Lundin When all questions from a tag are removed, the tag still exists for 24h (or something like that).

Comment: @Lundin the question that revived the tag was probably posted (or edited) by a high-rep user, but the question got deleted. Still the tag could've then be applied to other questions while the initial question was still up.

Comment: Likely, the question didn't get deleted but someone would have fixed the tags.

Comment: FYI, this is another of those tags that are "stuck"/aren't being fully removed because it's on an Article draft. I'm working with the Collectives team on addressing the underlying issue.

Comment: I think it wasn't stuck when I initially posted the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tag (along with many other tags created on draft Articles) has now been cleaned up.

As I indicated in an earlier comment, this was one of several tags that was "stuck" due to being on a draft Article. There were a few issues involved here; originally, Article drafts allowed authors to create tags without needing the [create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege or preventing blocked tags from being added; in addition, the tags would not be cleaned up by the system automatically, because they were present on Article drafts and could not be removed by anyone without editing permissions on those Articles.

The Collectives team recently went through and did a cleanup of tags created on Article drafts. I worked with the mods to get lists of the affected tags, and shared them with the Collectives team for cleanup; in all, we deleted 79 tags. The reputation requirement is also now being enforced for tag creation via Articles, as is the blocklist. The Collectives team is also working on making changes to the Article draft process to prevent this sort of problem in the future.

I've followed up with the site moderators, and confirmed that this tag block request is no longer necessary now that the underlying problem has been addressed. As such, I've retagged the request as  [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). Thank you all for your patience!